# Accumulate time

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a nc file where I have 'lon', 'lat', 'time', and 'foot'(representing footprints). For the foot variable I have foot(lon, lat, time). I did a 48h forward trajectory STILT simulation, which means that the time in foot contain 49 different "slices". I am now trying to accumulate that time so I can have a 2d map. I am not sure where to start. Below is my code:

```
footprints = "myfile.nc"
print(footprints)
 
with Dataset(footprints) as root:
    time = root.variables['time'][:]
    dates = num2date(time, root.variables['time'].units)
    print(dates[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S'))
    lats= root.variables['lat'][:]
    lons= root.variables['lon'][:]
    foot= root.variables['foot'][:, :, :]
 
Foot = np.arange(0,49)
for i in Foot:
   ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
   plt.contourf(lons[:], lats[:], np.squeeze(foot[i,:,:]), cmap = 'YlOrBr', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
   ax.set_extent([-178.546, -130.946, 50, 75])   # regional map, x=longitude, y=latitude (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)  
   ax.coastlines()
   ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
   plt.show()
```

I do not want to map only one slice/layer but all of them in one map. I should get one map but I am getting 49 of them.
Could you please help?

[When I open it with xr.open_dataset, the foot is shown below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEtK6.png)

Comment: show sample of your dataframe

Comment: `plt.show()` and the unchanging options should be outside the loop.

Comment: Yes, I edited my post and posted a link that shows foot when I retrieve the data with xr.open_dataset.

Comment: always put data as text in question, not image or link to external portal. We can't use values from image to test code and to create some solution. SO image is useless for us.